# Create swagger file in informatica cloud for Rest API v2 connector

Tags: informatica

I am new to informatica. I am trying to create a swagger file to call rest API.
I have given following information and getting error. The same information I am passing in postman and getting resulsts. Not sure what mistake I have done. Could anyone help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Screen shot and error highlighted, I can suggest to check the authentication.

In your screenshot, **AuthenticationType** is set to **None**, however the error clearly states that authentication required and is failing with **401 (Unauthorized Access) error.**

To double check, you can try connecting the same url in postman and I am sure you will get same error.

So, choose Authentication Type to relevant one. Basic is the most common which works on username / password combination.